# binarySearch with custom Comparator-object not checking first element

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make a custom Comparator-object to use with `java.util.Arrays.binarySearch`.

I want search the array for a String whose reverse value is equal to the reverse value of the target String element (dumb, I know, but it's just for learning).

However, when I attempt to run `binarySearch` on the array, all the elements match properly, except array element 0.

**Comparator:**

```
class SearchComparator<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparator<T> {
    public int compare(T s1, T s2) {

        String reverse1 = new StringBuilder((String)s1).reverse().toString();
        String reverse2 = new StringBuilder((String)s2).reverse().toString();

        return reverse1.equals(reverse2) ? 0 : -1;
    }
}
```

**Main function:**

```
String[] words = new String[]{"One", "Two", "Three", "Four"};
SearchComparator scmp = new SearchComparator();

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(words));

System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(words, "One", scmp));
System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(words, "Two", scmp));
System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(words, "Three", scmp));
System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(words, "Four", scmp));
```

**Output:**

```
[One, Two, Three, Four]
-5
1
2
3
```

What is up with `-5`? I don't know man.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `int compare(T s1, T s2)` from the `Comparator<T>` interface returns a number that indicates whether `s1` is less, equal to, or greater than `s2`; your code compares `s1` and `s2` for equality, which is incorrect.

You need to change the `return` line of your code to call the method for lexicographic comparison of `String` objects, like this:

```
return reverse1.compareTo(reverse2);
```

Another problem is that your array is not sorted in accordance with the same comparator. That is why you get negative indexes when you search in it. Add this line before making calls to `binarySearch` to fix the problem:

```
Arrays.sort(words, scmp);
```

Comment: Hm, that made sense. However, although it now finds element 1 properly, element 3 is now borked, showing as `-2`, `-5` etc. I've tried with different values. Any idea?